# Button that open a Modal don't execute my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have this button for opening a modal box and I whould like to execute a function of the pressed button at the same time opening the modal. The modal is opening but the function no.
Here is my code

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {

  $('#fileListTable tbody').append("<tr><td>" + item.File + "</td><td>" + item.DateUpload + "</td><td>" + `
                    <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> PDF </a>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Quest </a>

    ` + "</td > <td>" + `

      <button id="btnStatus`+ i +`" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-status" data-toggle="modal" href="#static"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Status</button>
    ` + "</td><td id='statusContainer"+ i +"'>" + item.Status + "</td><td>" + item.Comments + "</td></tr > ");


});
```

my function

```
   $('button[id^="btnStatus"]').click(function () {
    console.log('A button was clicked');   
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have dynamic element. So you need to attach click using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event

```
$('body').on('click', 'button[id^="btnStatus"]', function() {
    console.log('A button was clicked');   
});
```